# how to upload image file in form data in nestjs and typeorm and postgres

Tags: postgresql, swagger, nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

i am unable to track code for uploading with image

Please suggest me entity file, requestDTO and ResponseDTO in nestjs

043243

im working in my reutilizable code, and i have for you a FileService to Upload files to AWS S3 with NestJS.

The if conditional that you see in the code about cloudPlatform variable is because this is not the final code.

Eventually this service will be able to upload to many cloud platforms like GCP, Azure, AWS and FileSystem.